# JDBC Driver does not work with GWT?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jdbc

I want to access to an external MySQL server from my server using GWT, I added the mysql-connector jar to the build path and in war/WEB-INF/lib

Although I get this exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is a restricted
>   class. Please see the Google  App
>   Engine developer's guide for more
>   details.

Any ideas? Would jdbc driver be on a black-list?

Comment: You can only make rpc calls their server endpoints from gwt. You can't interact with the server's resources directly from gwt. Is this error occurring on the server, or on the client? What is the path of the class that the error is occurring in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine doesn't support JDBC. Maybe your project is set to target App Engine. If you're using Eclipse, right click the project, choose properties, and under "Google>App Engine" deselect "Use Google App Engine".

Comment: Ho, that's good to know.. And I need App Engine.. Would you know of an alternative for JDBC that would work with the App Engine?

Comment: App Engine uses BigTable - Google own datastore solution that can scale to handle google-size traffic. You can connect to it using JDO or JPA. Check out http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html for further info. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems Google has not yet released JDBC support..